# Migrating from 2.3 to 3.0 paginated results have OrderedDict in JSON

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am attempting to upgrade Django REST Framework from 2.3.14 to 3.0.5 My functional tests are failing because 3.0 is not returning correct JSON.

In 2.3 I get

```
{'results': [{'id': 2}, ...
```

but in 3.0 the JSON is not rendered correctly leaving an OrderedDict

```
{'results': [OrderedDict([('id', 2), ...
```

I'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.6. Can anyone tell me what I need to change to get the renderer to render correctly?

Comment: In DRF 3.x the serialization mechanism was changed slightly so that you can get different results from the serializer, comparing to DRF 2.x. From what I see, you are trying to compare a list containing dicts with one containing ordered dicts. Is the order the same in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization mechanism was slightly changed (improved) in DRF 3.x comparing to 2.x.

Therefore `response.data` contains the raw serialized python representation of the resource (either list or single item). If you want to test the equality with the final rendered representation (the JSON) you should use `response.content` (which uses `.data` but also applies the configured renderers).

Answer (score 0):

I was asserting against response.data which worked in 2.3. In 3.0 that no longer worked, but asserting against response.content does work.

```
self.assertDictEqual(
    json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')),
    { ...
```